# C# Unity serialization Vector3 types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deserialization

I'have this problem. (sorry for the links but I'm not allowed to insert images yet).
I would like to serialize the position, rotation, name and current scene of a gameObject.
But only the object name of the current scene (strings) works fine, not the position data (Vector3 type) and rotation (Quaternion type).
This is the class to be serialized, very simple:

```
[Serializable]
     public class SpaceObjectData
     {


         [DataMember]
         public string sObjectName;

         [DataMember]
         public Vector3 transformPosition;

         [DataMember]
         public Quaternion transformRotation;

         [DataMember]
         public string sceneLocation;



     }
```

This is the code for serialize my class and and save it on file :

```
         public void SetState()
     {

         // Stream the file with a File Stream. (Note that File.Create() 'Creates' or 'Overwrites' a file.)
         FileStream file = File.Create(path);

         //Serialize to xml
         DataContractSerializer bf = new DataContractSerializer(ObjectData.GetType());
         MemoryStream streamer = new MemoryStream();

         //Serialize the file
         bf.WriteObject(streamer, ObjectData);
         streamer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

         //Save to disk
         file.Write(streamer.GetBuffer(), 0, streamer.GetBuffer().Length);

         file.Close();


     }
```

This is the saved file code:

[XML saved code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t08C.png)

everything seems OK
This is the function to read the file and deserialize the stream:

```
  public void GetState()
         {



         if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
         {

             string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);


             using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
                 stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                 stream.Position = 0;
                 DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer((ObjectData.GetType()));
                 ObjectData = (SpaceObjectData)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

             }



             print(ObjectData.sObjectName); //output OK
             print(ObjectData.sceneLocation); //output OK
             print(ObjectData.transformPosition); //output wrong (always 0,0,0)
             print(ObjectData.transformRotation);  //output wrong (always 0,0,0,0)

         }
     }
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvLKm.png)

Where is that wrong?
Why do not you read the Vector3 and Quaternion data?
How should I save the Vector3 and Quaternions to be able to deserialize and read them?

Comment: Don't use images for code, post it directly.

Comment: Ok, I edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

`Vector3` and `Quaternion` are Unity classes. I doubt they are serializable with `DataContractSerializer`, which typically is what you are indicating when you use the [[DataMember]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

Consider using the built-in Unity serializer (you can remove all the `[DataMember]` attributes from your members since they are `public` and thus automatically serialized):

```
using System.IO;

//Save your SpaceObjectData object to a file, as a json string.
string data = JsonUtility.ToJson(yourSpaceDataObject, true); //pretty print!
File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);

//Read your SpaceObjectData from file
string retrievedData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
SpaceObjectData retrievedObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<SpaceObjectData>(retrievedData);
```